# calling SAS macro from matlab

Tags: matlab, sas

I was wondering if there is a way to call SAS macro from matlab

I need to the following

1) Call macro in SAS - Outputs to spreadsheets

2) Read the SAS output spreadsheet in MATLAB - Do some work - Output to spreadsheet

3) Read the Matlab output spreadsheet in SAS- Do some work - Output to spreadsheet

Is there a way I can call my SAS macros directly from MATLAB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to call a SAS program through a command line call.  Write a simple SAS program to do what you need.  You can pass a parameter string to SAS through the -SYSPARM option.

`sas myprog.sas -sysparm blah`

Then in your SAS program call what you need to call and reference the parameter with the &SYSPARM macro variable.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-sysop-sysparm.htm